# Trying to print a dynamic array of structs from a file

Tags: c

So basically, I'm trying to write a program that:

1. reads a dynamic array of structs of an unknown size;
2. writes it into file;
3. prints it on the screen.

All of that while using different functions and a dynamic array of struct. This is the code I'm working on; the printing function is not working correctly, it appears that the data  gets lost in the midst of all the operations :/ can someone please show me how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_CARS "cars.txt"

typedef struct car 
{
    long int id;
    char name[100];
}Car;

void reading(Car *vec){

    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &vec->id);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", vec->name);

    FILE *fab = fopen(FILE_CARS, "ab+");
    fwrite(&vec, sizeof(Car), 1, fab);
    fclose(fab);
}

void printing(Car *vec){

    //vec = (Car*) malloc(sizeof(Car));

    FILE *fr = fopen(FILE_CARS, "rb");

    while(fread(vec, sizeof(Car), 1, fr)){
        printf("\nID: %d\n", vec->id);
        printf("Name: %s\n", vec->name);
    }

    fclose(fr);
}


int main(){
    int op;

    Car *vec = (Car*) malloc (sizeof(Car));
    
    do{
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch(op){
            case 1:
                reading(vec);
                break;
            case 2:
                printing(vec);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("End of program");
                break;
            default:
                printf("invalid option");
        }

    }while(op != 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
fwrite(&vec, sizeof(Car), 1, fab);
```

You are writing *the pointer*, which will be useless, to the file.
This is also dangerous because `sizeof(Car)` is typically larger than pointers and out-of-bound read will occur.

Use this line without `&` instead:

```
fwrite(vec, sizeof(Car), 1, fab);
```

Comment: _You are writing the pointer_...  Isn't `vec` the pointer?  i.e. `&vec` would be a pointer to a pointer, (i.e. equivalent to a `Car **`  in prototype, which is wrong), and should have thrown a compiler error.

Comment: @ryyker `vec` is a pointer to a data of `Car`. `&vec` is a pointer to a data of `Car*`. Both are pointers. The first argument of `fwrite` is `const void*` and it accepts any pointers. Therefore no compiler errors are thrown. `fwrite` will write what is pointed at by the passed pointer to the file.